# Merging two dataframes while seeking forward

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have two `Pandas` DataFrames that i need to merge to get the full history of a group of employees.

Both frames contains the employee **ID** and a **timestamp** for when the data was valid. But the timestamps in one table are sometimes a bit "late" meaning that the second dataframe has a timestamp is either *on* or *after* the timestamp in the first dataframe.

##### Example Data

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [1000, 1000, 1002, 1003, 1004],
        'Start Date': [
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01')
    ],
        'Name': ['Joe', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Martin', 'Jane']
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [1000, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1004],
        'Start Date': [
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-04-05'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01'),
            pd.Timestamp('2021-01-10')
    ],
        'Position': ['Operator', 'Operator', 'Manager', 'Operator', 'Operator']})

df = df.merge(df2, how='left', on=['ID', 'Start Date'])
print(df)
```

##### Outputs

df

```
     ID Start Date    Name
0  1000 2021-01-01     Joe
1  1000 2021-01-01    Bill
2  1002 2021-04-01    Bill
3  1003 2021-01-01  Martin
4  1004 2021-01-01    Jane
```

df2

```
     ID Start Date  Position
0  1000 2021-01-01  Operator
1  1002 2021-01-01  Operator
2  1002 2021-04-05   Manager
3  1003 2021-01-01  Operator
4  1004 2021-01-10  Operator
```

merged df

```
     ID Start Date    Name  Position
0  1000 2021-01-01     Joe  Operator
1  1000 2021-01-01    Bill  Operator
2  1002 2021-04-01    Bill       NaN
3  1003 2021-01-01  Martin  Operator
4  1004 2021-01-01    Jane       NaN
```

I want to either arrange the code, or modify the data, so that the data for bill and Jane in one dataframe is merged with the shifted lines from the other data frame.

Some solutions that I have thought about (but don't know how to do) are:

- Fill the data in the second dataframe so that all all lines are represented within a given date range (e.g. make sure that Bills "Manager" title exist on all dates from 2021-01-02 and onwards and so on for all IDs)
- Exchange the merge command with one that is allowed to "seek forward" in the second dataframe until it finds a match.

Comment: if you can, kindly break down your explanation a bit more, with respect to your shared data. You can ignore this comment, if @BENY's solution suffices

Answer (score -1):

I'm am not sure I understood the same as BENY, I feel it makes more sense to keep only the latest per ID?

```
(df.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID', suffixes=('_drop', ''))
   .loc[lambda d: ~d['ID'].duplicated(keep='last')]
   .drop('Start Date_drop', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
     ID    Name Start Date  Position
1  1000    Bill 2021-01-01  Operator
3  1002    Bill 2021-04-05   Manager
4  1003  Martin 2021-01-01  Operator
5  1004    Jane 2021-01-10  Operator
```

Comment: Yes, I failed to specify that my intention with this method is to build a full employee history from different sets of data, so I do want to keep all lines. But thank you for a tip in case that is not needed.